# Why Can't I Center My Tabs?

Tags: html, css, tabs, center, blogger

I've tried adding the CSS, but I can not get my tabs bar to center on blogger- any suggestions? I tried adding:

```
.PageList {
   text-align:center !important;
 }

.PageList li {
   display:inline !important;
   float:none !important;
 }
```

But this does not seem to do anything.

Comment: Try giving the `.PageList` some **fixed** `width` and `margin:0 auto`.

Comment: It seems ok http://jsfiddle.net/U74cx/
It also works without !important and without the extra "float:none"

Answer (score 0):

```
.PageList{
    width:1000px;    //assuming the width to be 1000px
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

This `css` code added to your css will give you the required effect.

This can be another alternative `css` code

```
body{
width:100%;
}

.PageList{
width:200px; //your width
margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: neither of those do anything for my code.  It doesn't change it all.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job.

```
.PageList {
padding-left: 0;
margin: 20px 0;
text-align: center;
list-style: none;
}

.PageList li {
display: inline;
width:100px;
background:#ddd;
padding:10px;
color:#fff;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cw9C8/

Answer (score -1):

use fixed width & position it absolute try this

```
.pagelist{
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 50%;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;

}
```

Comment: Why should he add position: absolute?

Comment: it should positioned relative to its first positioned ancestor element

Comment: You don't need positions for this

Comment: if margin:0 auto, not working then it is better to use positions

Comment: What do you mean "not working?" Everything works if its right.. We don't position: absolute whatever doesn't seem to be where we want it to be :)

Comment: yeah agreed :) @Naele

Comment: http://icantaffordmylifestyle.blogspot.com/ Here is my blog and none of the other options have worked